# What do you think this number refers/refer to?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I am confused on the usage of 'refer to' and 'refers to'. 'Refers to' sounds natural, but 'number' is singular so are we supposed to use 'refer to' as it is singular?

***What do you think this number refers to /refer to?***

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is right. A singular noun functioning as a subject takes a singular verb and a plural noun takes a plural verb. But nouns and verbs have different inflections. Plural nouns take an **s** but plural verbs *don't*; singular verbs take an **s** but plural verbs *don't*. So the correct one is,

> What do you think this number **refers** to